# 10.8 standard share icon - where to get it?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, toolbar, osx-mountain-lion, nsbundle

I would like to add a "share" button in my Mac app, like Safari and other apps have in OS X 10.8.

Is it possible to get this icon programmatically from another bundle on runtime? Or should I make a copy of it and include it in my app bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameShareTemplate]` will give you an NSImage with the default share image. You don't need to include a copy of the image since it is a system resource (at least, in 10.8. It is a different story if it is 10.7). There is a list of other system provided icons [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/SystemProvidedIcons/SystemProvidedIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH5-SW2).

You may also want to look up `NSSharingServicePicker` if you will be implementing a standard share menu.

Comment: Is there a way to change the colour of the image?